# Зачем писать перед скобками еще раз oldPrice?

Tags: javascript

Я только начал изучать , простите за вопрос :)
Есть задача
Время похода по магазинам!
В магазине все продается с 20%-ной скидкой.
Вам дана программа, которая принимает цену товара в качестве входных данных. Дополните программу, чтобы она выводила в консоль цену со скидкой.

Пример вводных данных
100

Пример выходных данных
80

Объяснение
Поскольку 20 процентов от 100 равняется 20 (100 * 20/100), цена со скидкой будет 80 (100 - 20).

Я решил её так

```
function main() {
var oldPrice = parseInt(readLine(), 10)
// ваш код
var skidka = 20;
console.log(oldPrice-(oldPrice*skidka/100))
```

}

Вопрос в том,  зачем писать old Price перед скобками , если результат по факту в скобках ?

Comment: У вас же в объяснении все написано

Comment: ```100*20/100 = 20``` сумма которую сэкономят клиенты. ```100-20=80``` сумма к оплате. Поспите, может устали ведь решение правильное)

Comment: @Locker  благодарю )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите, в Вашем console.log вы выполняете
(oldPrice-(oldPrice*skidka/100)), просто обычное математическое уравнение

(стараяЦена - (стараяЦена * скидка / 100))
или
(100 - (100 * 20/100))

Сначала выполняется то, что в скобках. Потом то, что вне них.
А результат всего этого выведется в console.log(результат)

Вы бы могли сделать вот так вот

```
function main() {
  let oldPrice = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
  
  let skidka = 20;
  let result = oldPrice-(oldPrice*skidka/100);
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо, помогли :)